# How can I switch applications on iPhone or iPad by keyboard like "Windows key + tab" on Windows?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, switching

I like typing by keyboard while using iPhone and iPad. But when I switch applications(e.g. between Safari and memo application), I have to the push home putton on the devices'. It is very frustrating. Does anybody know how to switch applications by keyboard like "Windows key + tab" on Windows?

Comment: I use Command-Tab, but that's for OS X, not for iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a MacOS/iOS BT keyboard with the Option and Command (aka clover leaf or open Apple) keys, then this should help you out…

iPad Navigation Keyboard Commands
Basic keyboard navigation shortcuts on iPad are as follows:

Control+Option+H – Home button
Control+Option+H+H – Show multitask bar
Control+Option+i – Item chooser
Escape – Back button
Right Arrow – next item
Left Arrow – previous item
Up + Down Arrows simultaneously – tap selected item
Option + Down Arrow – scroll down
Option + Up Arrow – scroll up
Option + Left or Right Arrow – scroll left or right
Control+Option+S – turn VoiceOver speech on or off
iPad App Switcher Keyboard Commands
Arguably the most useful set of commands are related to app switching:

Command+Shift+Tab – switch to the previous app
Command+Tab – switch back to the original app
Left+Right Arrow, then Option + Left or Option+Right – navigate through Dock

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/01/ipad-keyboard-navigation-shortcuts/
More shortcuts: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/11/keyboard-shortcuts-ipad-iphone.html

Answer (score 3):

For iPad, ensure that multitasking gestures are turned on in "Settings > General > Multitasking Gestures". Instructions to switch between applications are right below the button.

IPhones do not support task switching with a Bluetooth keyboard.

On iPhones equipped with a 3D Touch screen, you can switch applications by force pressing on the left-most corner of the screen. This will open the task switching view.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 13, iPhone also supports controlling iPhone with an external keyboard.

> **Control iPhone with an external keyboard**
>
> If you have difficulty using the touchscreen, you can control your iPhone using shortcuts on Magic Keyboard (sold separately).
>
> 1. Go to Settings  > Accessibility > Keyboards, tap Full Keyboard Access,
>    then turn on Full Keyboard Access.
> 2. Control your iPhone using keyboard shortcuts.

To perform "Switching Apps", you can press **`Tab-A`** as a shortcut.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/keyboards-ipha7c3927eb/14.0/ios/14.0

Comment: This works on iPhone 5 SE!  Thanks for this tip! 